# c# Looping through directory, finding XML in each directory and, if & present replace with &amp; - Save

Tags: c#, xml, foreach, system.io.file

I would love to have the XML write correctly but the file is coming to us from a 3rd party, who we have no control over. (they are another vendor of our customer)

So with that in mind: 
They send us a zip of folders and sub-folders (in each of the sub folders there will be an XML)
The XML which they send us has & in place of &amp (every & is like this but not every XML will have a &); 
Using my code I can (on console at least) loop through each of the subs, find the xml, find the line with the & (if there is one) and change it to &

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);
                String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(d);
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (lines[i].Contains("&"))
                    {
                        string line = lines[i];
                        line = line.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                        Console.WriteLine(line);

                    }

                }
            }
```

In the last "Console.WriteLine(line);" it shows that the & is changed (in memory at least) but when I use the "System.IO.File" if still populates with the original &.

Comment: You are writing the original lines array out to the new file.  Try `lines[i] = line.Replace...`.  There are other problems with your code, such as the fact that you repeatedly write all lines out to the file on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks Joe, the System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(d, lines); was a mis-paste by myself. I removed it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains("&"))
        {
            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("&", "&amp;");                             
        }
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(d, lines);
}
```

As Joe mentioned in the comments, your original code was writing to the file during the loop over the lines in the file.  I also replaced your hard coded file path in the File.WriteAllLines() to the foreach variable

Comment: I, obviously, did not know that you could "lines[i] = lines[i].Replace". Perfect

Answer (score 2):

To save some time typing, instead of that loop, do something like:

```
lines = lines.Select(x => x.Replace("&", "&amp")).ToArray();
```